# Square of the angle bisector in a triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles

The question is:

> Prove that the square of the length, '$d$' of the angle bisector $AL$
>   of $\angle A$ meeting $BC$ at $L$ in a  $\Delta ABC$ is   $$bc \left(1- \left (\frac{a}{b+c}\right)^2\right).$$

I found this problem in a worksheet on the topic Stewart's theorem. But any other ways of solving may also be used. I'm sorry, I could not provide a diagram for this question as the site said it had some problems with that.

What I have tried:
I labelled $BL$ as $m$ and $LC$ as $n$. So according to Stewart's theorem,
$$a(mn+d^2)=b^2m+c^2n$$
I rearranged it to get $d^2$ on the LHS, as that is what we need. So I got
$$d^2= \frac{b^2m+c^2n-amn}{a}. $$
$$ d^2=b^2\cdot\frac{m}{a}+c^2\cdot\frac{n}{a}-mn$$ 
Then taking $m=a-n$, I got
$$d^2=b^2-\frac{n}{a}(b^2-c^2)-an+n^2.$$

I am not able to get rid of $n$. I tried using the cosine rule but that didn't help.
Any thoughts over this?

Comment: Please be careful with tagging - the algebraic-geometry tag "... should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry," per the tag wiki description.

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't know that. Thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

By the Stewart's theorem

\begin{align}
c^2u+b^2(a-u)&=a(d^2+(a-u)u)
,\\
d^2&=\frac 1a\,(c^2u+b^2(a-u))-(a-u)u
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}

by  [the angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem),

\begin{align}
b\,(a-u)&=c\,u
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
u&=\frac {ab}{b+c}
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
a-u&= \frac{ac}{b+c}
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

Combination of \eqref{1} with \eqref{3} and \eqref{4} gives
\begin{align}
d^2&
=\frac{bc((b+c)^2-a^2)}{(b+c)^2}
=bc\left(1-\frac{a^2}{(b+c)^2}\right)
.
\end{align}

Comment: I understood everything else, but how did you get $\Large u=\frac {ab}{b+c}
,\quad
a-u= \frac{ac}{b+c}$

Comment: @Aniket Gupta:
\eqref{3} is a solution to \eqref{2};
substitute \eqref{3} into the right-hand side of \eqref{2},
divide the result by $b$ and you get \eqref{4}.

Comment: Brilliant! $(+1)$